# CSS transition effect on menus using php and results from database

Tags: php, css

I am trying to pull a series of relevant category headings from the database - which is fine. Then, when the user hovers over those headings, menu items are pulled from another table and shown using css hover transition.

My css is as follows:

```
<style>
.nav ul { *zoom:1; list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; background:#333; }
.nav ul:before,.nav ul:after { content:""; display:table; }
.nav ul:after { clear:both; }
.nav ul > li { float:left; position:relative; }
.nav a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px 20px;
    line-height:1.2em;
    color:#fff;
    border-left:1px solid #595959;
}

.nav a:hover { text-decoration:none; background:#595959; }
.nav li ul { background:#273754; }
.nav li ul li { width:200px; }
.nav li ul a { border:none; }
.nav li ul a:hover { background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2); }

/* SLIDE */
.nav li ul { position:absolute; left:0; top:36px; z-index:1; }

.nav li ul li {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:0;
    -webkit-transition:height 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition:height 200ms ease-in;
    -o-transition:height 200ms ease-in;
    transition:height 200ms ease-in;
}

.nav ul > li:hover ul li { height:36px; }
</style>
```

and the rest is as so:

```
<nav class="nav">
<ul>
    <?php
    $getSubjectsQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM item_subject LEFT JOIN item_sub_menu ON item_subject.sub_id = item_sub_menu.sub_id");
    while($row = $getSubjectsQuery->fetch()){
        echo '<li><a href="subject.php?subject='.$row['sub_id'].'" >'.$row['subject'].'</a>';
    echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li><a href="subject.php?subject='.$row['sub_id'].'" >'.$row['name'].'</a></li>';
    echo '</ul></li>';
    }
    ?>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I, of course, have the relevant database connection/header includes too...

Now, at present with the current coding i can display all the 'menu headings' that i want, and when i hover over a 'menu heading' that has 'sub menus' only ONE will show. what i am wanting to do is list ALL relevant 'sub menus' to relevant 'menu headings':

```
MENU 1 -> SUB 1
MENU 2 -> SUB 1 | SUB 2 | SUB 3
MENU 3 ->
MENU 4 -> SUB 1 | SUB 2
```

Tthe area I think i need to be looking at is:

```
echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li><a href="subject.php?subject='.$row['sub_id'].'" >'.$row['name'].'</a></li>';
    echo '</ul></li>';
```

To somehow count/collect all of the relevant 'Sub Menus' so that they are all listed.

I have lost track of the different things iv tried and have had to redo everything into the simplest form i could. i was mostly looking at an additional while loop to pull the 'sub menus', with a relationship of 'sub_id' between the 2 but had no joy in doing so.

Could anyone please advise how i should best be going about this, what am I missing to pull all results for the 'sub_menus'?

EDIT: what I have tried so far:

at present the results I get are:

```
MENU 1 -> SUB 1
MENU 1 -> SUB 2 // MENU 1 has been listed twice, once for each matching SUB
MENU 2 -> SUB 3
MENU 3 ->
```

If I add: "GROUP BY item_subject.sub_id", then I get:

```
MENU 1 -> SUB 1 // SUB 2 is missing from here
MENU 2 -> SUB 3
MENU 3 ->
```

Comment: You have not made clear why your approach does not work. Are there errors, or the results are displayed but not in the format you expected?

Comment: Side note: My brief understanding of your code leads me to believe that as a menu option is selected, a new connection is made to the server - If true, then this is a waste of resources and will eventually slow the user down. I suggest you load your entire menu and any submenu options initially, then display them. (Resulting in less pain on your server and better response to the user).

Comment: do you mean to perform a single SQL query that gets all results, and then extract the relevant information? as that is what i am trying to do at present.

Comment: Your coding combines html, javascript and php. While its acceptable (recommended in some circles) I am just less keen with your last chunk of code (where PHP echo's <ul>, <li> and </ul>. Data written to tables are a good example where your approach would give poor performance as the entire table would not display until all data is served. Drawing the screen and then perhaps doing an ajax connection, get the data, then write to the screen would be my approach. This method is more readable since you can keep html, javascript and php code into different files.

Comment: Can you perform a View Source of your code and share it here? I'm thinking you have probably not closed your <ul> or <li> properly - or some part of PHP wasn't closed properly. A view from the client would help resolve this.

Comment: ah yes, i will create an additional post with RE: to discussing that as its something i do want to improve upon/learn more about... at present i literally mix things together dipping in and out of PHP and echoing HTML all over the place :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok... so after an estimated 11hrs combined time at this, i have solved my problem.

what i did was split my query into 2 parts and set a variable after the first query to reference in the second, like so:

```
<nav class="nav">
<ul>
    <?php
    $getSubjectsQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM item_subject");
    while($row = $getSubjectsQuery->fetch()){
    $menu = $row['sub_id'];

                echo '<li><a href="subject.php?subject='.$row['sub_id'].'" >'.$row['subject'].'</a>';
    echo '<ul>';
    $getSubQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM item_sub_menu where sub_id = '$menu'");
        while($sub_row = $getSubQuery->fetch()){
            echo '<li><a href="subject.php?subject='.$row['sub_id'].'" >'.$sub_row['name'].'</a></li>';
        }
    echo '</ul></li>';
    }

    ?>
</ul>
</nav>
```

after testing with extra data everything works great!

with RE: to now having 2 queries, is it at all possible to combine them into just one from what im working with?